# Инспектор chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли вытащить полностью css из инспектора в еще загруженном окне браузера? Случайно затерся файл(

Answer (score 1):

Загруженную копию файла можно найти во вкладке инспектора Sources.